# How to use SUMPRODUCT formula for calculating alphanumeric values of different cells placed in single row... not in different rows..?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, alphanumeric

How to use SUMPRODUCT formula for calculating alphanumeric values of different cells placed in single row, not in different rows?

Comment: Hi Shafiq, would you have any sample input and desired output? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alpha Numeric Validation in Microsoft Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65377328/alpha-numeric-validation-in-microsoft-excel)

Comment: @ UdonN00dle

21.0 pkt

22.0 pkt

33.0 pkt

__________   
  
This given data is placed in different rows of a single column in MS-Excel so it is easy to calculate the alphanumeric value of these rows by the following formula:
 =SUMPRODUCT(VALUE(LEFT(#:#,LEN(#:#)-3)))
but if the same date is placed in a single row of different columns like:
21.0 pkt 22.0 pkt  12.0 pkt 
How could I calculate its alphanumeric value and get the desired result of 76. 
hope it will help in understanding the problem.
Thank you for your quick response.